# Event Handler Problem in Windows Service

Tags: c#, events, windows-services, timer

I am going nuts. I can't figure out the problem.

I have a windows service that has a simple timer method. If I start the service, it always gives out exception at onTimerElapsed event. But If I write my XMLOperation methods in a different method(but not timer which I only need) and call it from program.cs, it works just fine. The working code is at the bottom also.

```
partial class DatabaseService : ServiceBase
{
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    public DatabaseService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {   
        timer.Interval = 10000;
        timer.Enabled = true;

        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(onElapsedTime);
        timer.Start();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        timer.Enabled = false;
    }

    public void onElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            XMLOperations operation = new XMLOperations();
            operation.WebServiceFlexiCampaigns("http://www.flexi.com.tr/data/xml/pazaryeri/mobil.xml");
            operation.WebServiceShopMilesCampaignsXMLRead("http://www.shopandmiles.com/xml/3_119_3.xml");
            operation.WebServiceBonusCampaignsXMLRead("http://www.bonus.com.tr/apps/getcampaignxml.aspx?type=campaigns");
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            StreamWriter SW;
            SW = File.CreateText("c:\\1.txt");
            SW.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            SW.Close();
        }

    }
```

here is the working one, but this time I could not manage to work that code in periods of time like I can do in timer event.  I call test method manually from program.cs

```
partial class DatabaseService : ServiceBase
{
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    public DatabaseService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        timer.Interval = 10000;
        timer.Enabled = true;

        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(onElapsedTime);
        timer.Start();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        timer.Enabled = false;
    }
    public void test()
    {
        try
        {
            XMLOperations operation = new XMLOperations();
            operation.WebServiceFlexiCampaigns("http://www.flexi.com.tr/data/xml/pazaryeri/mobil.xml");
            operation.WebServiceShopMilesCampaignsXMLRead("http://www.shopandmiles.com/xml/3_119_3.xml");
            operation.WebServiceBonusCampaignsXMLRead("http://www.bonus.com.tr/apps/getcampaignxml.aspx?type=campaigns");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            StreamWriter SW;
            SW = File.CreateText("c:\\1111.txt");
            SW.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            SW.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: for better practice, you should do using(StreamWriter SW = File.CreateText("c:\\1111.txt")) { SW.WriteLine(ex.Message); }

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post the output that goes to `1.txt` from the failing version.  My guess is a permissions problem with the service.  What account does it run under?  the same as your login id when you run the working (non-service) code?

Comment: So far, in your second case, where is define the method "onElapsedTime". Also in the first case, what is the exception you have ?

Comment: It is very strange that i am getting "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." as exception. By the way this exception is only thrown in 1st and 2nd method of onElapsedTime event. If I only wirte the second one, it works just fine. In my second case I dont have on Elapsed time as I call test method from program.cs

Comment: It looks like regional / localization settings conflict on your machine / service.

Comment: How can I correct that localization problem?

Comment: Just wondering, side question - shouldn't you stop your timer when you are handling the elapsed event and start after you're done?

Comment: I have 3 methods doing pretty much same thing, reading XML. 2 of them doesnt work at all with timer, just one of them works

Answer (score 1):

You can try this thread (see SamAgain response):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/clr/thread/8fbca78b-5078-4a12-8abb-4051076febbb

Hope it will work.